# Using LINQPad with EF PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core, linqpad

I'm attempting to move my database from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. Everything is going fine, the migrations have been applied and I can connect to the instance within my applications using the entity context.

Using LINQPad I can connect directly to the database using the [PostgreSQL driver](http://www.linqpad.net/GetFile.aspx?richclient%20LINQPad.PostgreSQL.Driver.lpx). However I want to use the DLL entity context built by my project, previously LINQPad worked perfectly with SQL Server and .NET 4.6 before. Now however when specifying the DLL for dnx46 (.NET 4.6) I get the following error from the PostgresSQL connection string;

[image: Add DNX46 Connection]

My project is also cross compiled across .NET Core & .NET 4.6 - for various reasons. I have also tried to reference the EF Core DLL (using the Entity Framework V7 driver) but get a different error.

[image: Add NETSTANDARD16 Connection]

I'd be happy with a working solution for either framework.